# Webpack vs webpack-dev-server vs webpack-dev-middleware vs webpack-hot-middleware vs etc

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-dev-middleware

I'm starting working with `webpack` with a `node/express` environment developing a `ReactJS` server side rendered application with `react-router`. I'm getting very confused about the role of each webpack package for dev and prod (runtime) environments.

Here is the summary of my understanding:

`webpack`: Is a package, a tool to join together different pieces of an web application and bundle then in a single .js file (normally `bundle.js`). The result file is then served in a prod environment to be loaded by the application and contains all necessary components to run the code. Features include shrinking code, minifying, etc.

`webpack-dev-server`: Is a package that offers a **server** to process the website files. It also builds a single .js file (`bundle.js`) from client components but serves it in memory. It also has the option (`-hot`) to monitor all the building files and build a new bundle in memory in case of code changes. The server is served directly in the browser (ex: `http:/localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/whatever`). The combination of in memory loading, hot processing and browser serving let the user get the application updated on browser when the code changes, ideal for development environment.

***If I have doubts about the above text, I'm really not sure about the content below, so please advise me if necessary***

A common problem when using `webpack-dev-server` with `node/express` is that `webpack-dev-server` is a server, as is `node/express`. That makes this environment tricky to run both the client and some node/express code (an API etc.). ***NOTE: This is what I've faced but would be great to understand why does that happens in more details...***

`webpack-dev-middleware`: This is a middleware with same functions of `webpack-dev-server` (inmemory bundling, hot reloading), but in format that can be injected to the `server/express` application. In that way, you have a sort of server (the `webpack-dev-server`) insider the node server.  ***Oops: Is this a crazy dream ??? How can this piece solve the dev and prod equation and makes life simpler***

`webpack-hot-middleware`: This... ***Stuck here... found this piece when looking for `webpack-dev-middleware`... No idea how to use it.***

ENDNOTE: Sorry is there is any wrong thinking. I really need help in order to undestand these variants in a complex environment. If conveninent, please add more packages/data that will build the whole scenario.

Comment: None of the packages listed here are used on the server side in production - they're just developer tools. You'd use `webpack-dev-middleware` (and potentially `webpack-hot-middleware`) if you wanted to write your own custom development server. Unless there's a specific feature you want that `webpack-dev-server` doesn't have, you should just use that.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

### [`webpack`](https://webpack.js.org/)

As you've described, Webpack is a module bundler, it bundles various module formats primarily so they can be run in a browser. It offers both a [CLI](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/) and [Node API](https://webpack.js.org/api/node/).

### [`webpack-dev-middleware`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware)

Webpack Dev Middleware is middleware which can be mounted in an express server to serve the *latest compilation* of your bundle during development. This uses `webpack`'s Node API in [watch mode](https://webpack.js.org/api/node/#watching) and instead of outputting to the file system it [outputs to memory](https://github.com/webpack/memory-fs).

> For comparison, you might use something like [`express.static`](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) instead of this middleware in production.

### [`webpack-dev-server`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#webpack-dev-server)

Webpack Dev Server is itself an express *server* which uses `webpack-dev-middleware` to serve the latest bundle and additionally handles hot module replacement (HMR) requests for live module updates in the client.

### [`webpack-hot-middleware`](https://github.com/glenjamin/webpack-hot-middleware)

Webpack Hot Middleware is an alternative to `webpack-dev-server` but instead of starting a server itself it allows you to mount it in an existing / custom express server alongside `webpack-dev-middleware`.

Also...

### [`webpack-hot-server-middleware`](https://github.com/60frames/webpack-hot-server-middleware)

Just to confuse things even more, there's also Webpack Hot Server Middleware which is designed to be used alongside `webpack-dev-middleware` and `webpack-hot-middleware` to handle hot module replacement of server rendered apps.

Comment: For those in search of front-end vs back-end hot module replacement breakdown, please see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46086297/nodemon-and-or-hot-reloading-with-a-node-react-web-app Xlee does a good job explaining the requirements for each side -- server-side needing a restart, front-end allowing loading in updated javascript bundles.

Answer (score 7):

As of update in 2018 and considering the **webpack-dev-server** note on [its official GitHub page:](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server)

> Project in Maintenance Please note that webpack-dev-server is
>   presently in a maintenance-only mode and will not be accepting any
>   additional features in the near term. Most new feature requests can be
>   accomplished with Express middleware; please look into using the
>   before and after hooks in the documentation.

What would be the natural choice to build a webpack HMR ?

Comment: It also says `Use webpack-serve for a fast alternative. Use webpack-dev-server if you need to test on old browsers.` So you might want to try [webpack-serve](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-serve) .

Comment: The maintenance note has been removed. So I guess it's recommended again???  Maddening that such an important dev tool has such a terrible maintainer team around it.

Comment: webpack-serve is deprecated and as @CaptainFogetti said the maintenance note has been removed from webpack-dev-server as of today

Comment: webpack-dev-server is the Official webpack server for dev builds. It is well documented here https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver and even has built-in support for webpack-dev-middleware and http-proxy-middleware via configs. I would recommend using this unless you have a really complex setup in which case you would opt for webpack-dev-middleware