# How to use css preprocessors with angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, sass, single-page-application

I am new to the pre-processors world. How can I use them, in particular postcss and  lostgrid, with angular 7.

I am trying to apply [this code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BeLWeb) in angular. And as you can see it uses [postcss-cssnext](https://postcss.org/) and [lost-grid](http://lostgrid.org/).

```
@use postcss-cssnext;
@use lost;

@lost flexbox flex;
@lost gutter 0;

//more css code
```

How can I use these in my angular app?

*** EDIT ***

You can use the above code without pre-processors. I edited the code like so: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BeLWeb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now angular cli not support building postcss so you have to write custom webpack to handle it.

You must use postcss-loader package [here](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader)

and you have to use [custom-webpack](https://github.com/meltedspark/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack) to do that. Example can be found [here](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-webpack-config/)

Alternative soultions: Angular provide 3 pre processing css for you to use is sass,scss,less so you can choose base on your personal preference

To use angular cli with pre process css you can generate new angular cli project using

```
ng new my-app --style=scss
```

You can also set the --style flag with the following:

1. --style=scss
2. --style=sass
3. --style=less

Below is config in angular.json

```
  "projects": {
    "awesome": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
```

You can in schematics section I have scss preprocess css option you can change into scss, less, or sass

You can read this article [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-sass-with-the-angular-cli) for more info

Comment: What about if I want to use another pre-processor that is not one of the three? like postcss?

Comment: You want to minimize your css file using postcss ?

Comment: I want to use postcss in my angular project, like I said in the question

Comment: I dont think you can. Postcss also using js to transform the code you written into css just like you use sass, scss or less and it already request in github [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2420) [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1656) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1512). So until futher announcement I think can only use sass,less, scss

Comment: @YulePale so did my answer help you ?

Comment: I am trying to see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48129327/how-do-i-use-postcss-autoprefixer-in-angular) works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48129327/how-do-i-use-postcss-autoprefixer-in-angular

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193295/discussion-between-yulepale-and-tony-ngo).